# Complicated If statement

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having a hard time solving a problem.

The Objective is to look at Column B. If say Cell B1 contrains "Certain Text" or   "Certain Text 2" Then the Cell directly to it's left A1 in this case should return "Certain Text 3" Else "Certain Text 4". This process continues onto all the rows in Column B.

Please note that I have around 65,000 rows.

Thank you

Comment: this could be accomplished using a built-in function in excel, is there a reason that you want to use VBA scripts for it?

Comment: If it's possible to get the function to work with a single button then I'm happy to do so.

Comment: You can write it on the first row and double click on the bottom right corner, that will drop it down to the last one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put this into A1 and double-click the 'fill handle'.

```
=IF(OR(B1={"Certain Text", "Certain Text 2"}), "Certain Text 3", "Certain Text 4")
```

Comment: missing a `)` after the `} ` i think

Comment: Learned something new with the braces there! But will using an array slow down the file with 65k lines? Why not use `=IF(OR(B1=“Certain Text”,B1=“Certain Text”), “Certain Text 3”, “Certain Text 4”)`

Comment: No, an array of string literals isn't going to slow things down anymore that a two condition OR. It might be sped up if one condition was predominant; say 90% was going to be "Certain Text" then nested conditions with "Certain Text" first would be faster.

Comment: Thank you all so much for all your help. It has worked.